# How multiple index files can be used with Solrnet(lucene)?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I need to query two index files in solrnet. i will get ids from one index file and then will query other index files according to that IDs. I want to know is there any way in Solrnet to access more than one index files or simply can i modify solr.data.dir variable i solrnet on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have *just* [documented this](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess) on the SolrNet wiki.